# Read a "TXT" file in Dart

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

i was trying to read a .txt file (from assets) in items of a list, so i was doing this:

```
list.add(await rootBundle.loadString('assets/jolo.txt'));
```

It takes the whole document and put it in 'data', but at showing the list is empty.

So i tried something else:

```
new File('assets/jolo.txt')
  .openRead()
  .transform(utf8.decoder)
  .transform(new LineSplitter())
  .forEach((l) => list.add(Item(name: l)));
```

but that throws me an error:
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/jolo.txt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

What can i do? I'm using plain text for putting every line into an item for show the whole list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To load an asset you **must** use the bundle. `loadString` takes care of reading the asset and dealing with the encoding so you get a String. Use `LineSplitter.convert` on the string:

```
String jolo = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/jolo.txt');
List<Item> list =
    LineSplitter().convert(jolo).map((s) => Item(name: s)).toList();
```

Comment: I've tried your answer, thanks for your interest. It didn't work, but I think it's closer to the solution. Do you have any idea what to do? :(    . I have the error: type 'MappedListIterable<String, Item>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Item>'

Answer (score 1):

You may not be running in the directory that you think.
Try looking at Directory.current() to see where you are running.

Comment: Hi, i tried it but it returns me "/". Thats all. Also tried to use File.fromUri() but still not working. :(